# How can I fire a Javascript function when a standard visualforce page is loading in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

On standard salesforce page, I need to display some custom buttons based on some conditions. The decision to display the button or not is based on response from Apex method. As my page is standard visual force page, how can I trigger the JavaScript function before the page is loaded so that I can take a decision whether to display the button or not?

Comment: There used to be ways to inject your javascript into the standard pages, but salesforce put an end to that a few years ago. [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds-salesforce-classic-aloha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can display a custom button on standard salesforce page. but salesforce not allowed to make any call on load of standard page. Salesforce have a feature that is page layout. You can create different record type with page layout in that you can use custom button as your need.
2. On the other hand you can make a decision and filter when javascript custom button click and show error like 'you are not allowed to click this button'.